# how to use the POST method ( rest plugin - grails )?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm using the grails plugin:  [REST client facilities](http://grails.org/plugin/rest)
I can use the method Get like this (code from the grails rest plugin page):

```
withHttp(uri: "http://www.google.com") {
   def html = get(path : '/search', query : [q:'Groovy'])
   assert html.HEAD.size() == 1
   assert html.BODY.size() == 1
}
```

Does anyone know how to do the Post method?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [HTTPBuilder POST](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/post.html).